# Write Field output report via python in Abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm trying to write a field output report from the odb file. I keep getting a IOError, which I have no idea where is the problem of my script. Hope you guys can help on this!

This is the script I have for writing the field output report

```
o1 = session.openOdb(name='R:\ABAQUS\Job-5.odb')
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=o1)

odb = session.odbs['R:\ABAQUS\Job-5.odb']
session.writeFieldReport(fileNmae = 'abaqus.rpt', append = OFF, sortItem = "Node Label", 
                         odb = odb, step = 2, frame = 50, outputPosition = NODAL, 
      variable = (('CNORMF ASSEMBLY_DROP-SURF/ASSEMBLY_PART2INSTANCE_SURF-1',NODAL, ((INVARIANT, 'Magnitude'),)),)) 
odb.close()
```

This is the error that I get:

```
*Starting main file  [Kernel]: r:/ABAQUS/readOutput.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r:/ABAQUS/readOutput.py", line 27, in <module>
    NODAL, ((INVARIANT, 'Magnitude'),)),))
IOError: IOError: Empty filename
Exit from main file  [Kernel]: r:/ABAQUS/readOutput.py
```

I referred to my .rpy file for another odb file, which i did the exact same procedure, and the code is shown below. I ran this script and it works and writes the field report successfully.It does not throw this Empty filename error. However, when I use the same code for my other odb file, it throws that error.

```
o1 = session.openOdb(name='C:/Temp/Job-14.odb')
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=o1)
#: Model: C:/Temp/Job-14.odb
#: Number of Assemblies:         1
#: Number of Assembly instances: 0
#: Number of Part instances:     2
#: Number of Meshes:             2
#: Number of Element Sets:       5
#: Number of Node Sets:          6
#: Number of Steps:              2
#session.animationController.setValues(animationType=TIME_HISTORY, viewports=(
    #'Viewport: 1', ))
#session.animationController.play(duration=UNLIMITED)
#session.animationController.setValues(animationType=NONE)
#session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.setFrame(step=1, frame=20)
odb = session.odbs['C:/Temp/Job-14.odb']
session.writeFieldReport(fileName='abaqus.rpt', append=OFF, 
    sortItem='Node Label', odb=odb, step=1, frame=20, outputPosition=NODAL, 
    variable=(('CNORMF   ASSEMBLY_M_SURF-8/ASSEMBLY_S_SURF-8', NODAL, ((
    INVARIANT, 'Magnitude'), )), ))
odb.close()
```

Hope you guys can give me some clues !! Thank you!

Comment: For start, check if you have made a typo when copying the code or you really did write `fileNmae` in your first script.

Comment: OMG thanks so much! I can't believe i didn't notice this after reading so many times!! Thanks!